# A variety $X\subset\mathbb{A}^n$ has two disjoint components iff $A(X)$ is the product of 2 finitely generated reduced k-algebras

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

It is a homework:

> Show that a variety $X\subset\mathbb{A}^n$ has two disjoint components if and only if
>   the coordinate ring $A(X)$ may be written as the product of two finitely
>   generated reduced k-algebras.

I failed to work it out, could anyone give me some hints?

The coordinates ring $A(X)\cong R/\mathcal{I}(X)$, where $R=k[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$. I find it difficult to deal with this quotient ring and to factor it into a product of two subrings of this quotient. I guess if $X=V\cup W$, we need to do something with $A(V)=R/\mathcal{I}(V)$ and $A(W)=R/\mathcal{I}(W)$, but they are not subrings of $R/\mathcal{I}(X)$.

Could any help?

Answer (score 2):

Let $A=A(X)=R/I(X)$ be the coordinate ring of $X$.

> $X$ has two disjoint components if and only if there is a nontrivial
>   idempotent $e\in A$ (here nontrivial means $\neq 0,1$), if and only if
>   there is a decomposition $A=A/eA\times A/(e-1)A$.

If there is a nontrivial idempotent $e\in A$, then $V(e)$ and $D(e)=V(e-1)$ are both open and closed, and they are complement of each other (hence they are the seeked disjoint components):
$$X=V(e)\coprod D(e)=\textrm{Spec }(A/eA)\coprod \textrm{Spec }(A/(e-1)A)=\textrm{Spec }(A/eA\times A/(e-1)A).$$ So we get the claimed decomposition of $A$ as well.

Conversely, if $X$ has two disjoint components, you get a nontrivial idempotent by considering the function $X\to\mathbb A^1$ which sends the first component identically to $1$ and the second component identically to $0$. And given that idempotent, you have the decomposition of $A$ as above.